# cannot access public properties of one userControl (FirstControl.ascx) from another UserControl (SecondControl.ascx) in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-controls, properties

I have created a userconrol named `FirstControl.ascx` and `SecondControl.ascx` in Sharepoint. Both the controls automatically created under `CONTROLTEMPLATES\MySolution\..` folder

Within `SecondControl.ascx` I registered `FirstControl.ascx` as below:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/_controltemplates/15/MySolution/FirstControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="FirstControl" %>

<uc1:FirstControl ID="FirstControl1" runat="server" OnLoad="FirstControl1_Load" />
```

On code behinde `SecondControl.ascx.cs` file, I could not access public property `SelectedDateTime` of `FirstControl.ascx`

on `FirstControl.ascx.cs` file , I have this Public property declared:

```
public partial class FirstControl: UserControl
  {

        public delegate void SelectedDate(SelectedDateEventArgs e);
        public event SelectedDate OnSelectedDate;

    [Setting()]
    public DateTime SelectedDateTime
    {
                get
                {
                    return GetDateTime(txtDate.Text, txtTime.Text);
                }
                set
                {
                    hfDateTime.Value = value;
                }
    }
}
```

on `SecondControl.ascx.cs` file, I tried to access the public property `SelectedDateTime` But in the intellisence of FirstControl1., I could not find property `SelectedDateTime`

Comment: do both .cs files have same namespace?

Comment: Yes, both controls have same namespace. any idea to fix?